# Javascript game sprite loading

Tags: javascript, html

I don't really know how to accurately describe my problem but the issue is that when I play my javscript game and I call for enemies to spawn by adding them to an array, they load and update one by one as opposed to loading and updating together. This means that the game only loads one enemy on screen at a time as opposed to the game having as many enemies on screen as there are in the array. The weird part is that another function which uses the same system (called projectile) loads multiple items and updates them on screen.

The Functions themselves

```
function projectile(x, y, dx, dy, loaded) {
    var self = this;
    self.x = x;
    self.y = y;
    self.oldx = x;
    self.oldy = y;
    self.loaded = loaded;
    self.sprite = new Image();
    self.alive = true;
    self.sprite.onload = function () {
        self.loaded = true;
    }
    self.sprite.src = "/images/rock.png";
    self.dx = dx;
    self.dy = dy;
    self.project = function () {
        if (self.alive) {
            self.oldx = self.x;
            self.oldy = self.y;
            self.x += self.dx * 10;
            self.y += self.dy * 10;
            if (self.loaded) {
                gs.drawImage(self.sprite, self.x, self.y);
            }
        }
    }
}

function enemy(x, y, width, height, frames, levels, loaded, speed, health, damage) {
    var self = this;
    self.sprite = new Image();
    self.sprite.onload = function () {
        self.loaded = true;
    }
    self.sprite.src = "/images/sDog.png";
    self.x = x;
    self.y = y;
    self.dx = 0;
    self.dy = 0;
    self.w = width;
    self.h = height;
    self.f = frames - 1;
    self.l = levels;
    self.cf = 0;
    self.cl = 0;
    self.loaded = false;
    self.fps = 0;
    self.speed = speed;
    self.moving = false;
    self.health = health;
    self.damage = damage;

    self.update = function () {
        if (self.health > 0) {
            self.fps += 1;
            if (self.fps >= g_fps) {
                self.changeframe();
                self.fps = 0;
            }
            if (dog.health > 0) {
                if (dog.x + (dog.w / 2) > self.x + (self.w / 2)) {
                    self.dx = 1;
                }
                if (dog.x + (dog.w / 2) < self.x + (self.w / 2)) {
                    self.dx = -1;
                }
                if (dog.y + (dog.h / 2) > self.y + (self.h / 2)) {
                    self.dy = 1;
                }
                if (dog.y + (dog.h / 2) < self.y + (self.h / 2)) {
                    self.dy = -1;
                }
                for (i = 0; i < projectiles.length; i++) {
                    if (projectiles[i].x > self.x && projectiles[i].x < self.x + self.w && projectiles[i].y > self.y && projectiles[i].y < self.y + self.h && projectiles[i].alive) {
                        projectiles[i].alive = false;
                        self.health -= dog.damage;
                        self.x += projectiles[i].dx * dog.damage;
                        self.y += projectiles[i].dy * dog.damage;
                    }
                }
                if (dog.x > self.x && dog.x < self.x + self.w && dog.y > self.y && dog.y < self.y + self.h) {
                    dog.health -= self.damage;
                    dog.x += self.dx * self.damage;
                    dog.y += self.dy * self.damage;
                }
                self.x += self.dx * self.speed;
                self.y += self.dy * self.speed;
            }
        }
        if (self.loaded && self.health > 0) {
            gs.drawImage(self.sprite, self.cf * self.w, self.cl * self.h, self.w, self.h, self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h);
        }
    }
    self.changeframe = function () {
        if (self.health > 0) {
            if (self.cf > self.f - 1) {
                self.cf = 0;
            }
            else {
                self.cf += 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            self.cf = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

The calling of the functions

```
for (i = 0; i < projectiles.length; i++) {
        projectiles[i].project();
        if (projectiles[i].x < -50 || projectiles[i].x > c.width + 50 || projectiles[i].y < -50 || projectiles[i].y > c.width + 50) {
            projectiles[i].alive = false;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
        enemies[i].update();
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated, but this code looks like you could easily move many of the functions into `enemy.prototype` and `projectile.prototype`, which should improve performance and perhaps clean up your memory footprint considerably (I'm assuming you're creating them using `new`).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this right your enemies are actually being loaded correctly, however they are not being rendered until their sprites have been loaded (when `self.loaded == true`). Since your projectiles all share the same sprite (I assume) they all start being rendered at the same time, which is exactly when that sprite is loaded.

So nothing is wrong, but what you can do is add an else to your checks for `self == loaded` that draws a sort of placeholder (an idea would be a rectangle of the size of the object's bounding box) to provide a visual representation for your enemies before their sprites are ready. Another idea would be to have the game wait for all the sprites needed to be loaded before the gameloop gets first called.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately I'm still not seeing a location of where the other enemies are on the map

Comment: @user1994100 `if (self.health > 0) {if (self.loaded) {/* current action */} else {/* draw placeholder */}}`